# Moving data from a collection view cell to a new collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to pass the name of the organization to a new viewController. The problem is that when I pass the value from the collection view cell to a new label in the other viewController, multiple collectionView cells are displayed that repeat the same information. How would I change this so that once one cell from the first collectionView is selected, only that information will populate the other collectionView cell?

Here is the code for the first viewController.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var secondCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var valueToPass = Int()

var arrayOfOrganizations = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfOrganizations.count
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let secondCell = secondCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell
    secondCell.nameTextLabel.text = arrayOfOrganizations[indexPath.item]
    return secondCell
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    valueToPass = indexPath.item
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "MoveCollectionViewCell", sender: self)
    arrayOfOrganizations.remove(at: indexPath.item)
    self.secondCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    secondCollectionView.reloadData()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "MoveCollectionViewCell") {
        let destination = segue.destination as! MessagesViewController
        destination.valueToPass = arrayOfOrganizations[valueToPass]
    }
}

}


class SecondCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Here is the code for my second viewController.

```
import UIKit

class MessagesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var messagesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var valueToPass = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return valueToPass.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "messagesViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MessagesViewCell
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    if (valueToPass == "one") {
        cell.textLabel.text = "one"
    }
    if (valueToPass == "two") {
        cell.textLabel.text = "two"
    }
    if (valueToPass == "three") {
        cell.textLabel.text = "three"
    }
    if (valueToPass == "four") {
        cell.textLabel.text = "four"
    }
    return cell
}

}

class MessagesViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `numberOfItemsInSection` is returning the size of the string valueToPass (the number of characters), is this what you want? Because If you have only one value the return of that function should be 1.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return valueToPass.count // Number of character in valueToPass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're numberOfItemsInSection collectionView method returns valueToPass.count changed it to 1.